# Access DB query result extract

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have written an Access query, it contains 10 different tables.
after I view the table I get 300000+ records.
How can I now Extract or save this result to any other form like EXCEL or CSV or DB or even ACCESS?
I have used Excel and CSV as export it says not more than 65000 rows allowed
ODBC connection says - the data is too long.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have the data in access - why store it again - simply query it?

Comment: Why do you need to save over 300,000 rows of information again?

Comment: @Minty - I have it along with many other tables, What I care is only the output table. Also I have to share the file

Comment: @SeanLange Its a set of information aquried after quering lot of random data. My End goal is to save my output.

Comment: But 300,000 rows is a lot of information to copy. Why not save the query and run it when you need to see the results? And if you are routinely retrieving that many rows of data perhaps it is time you stop using Access.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't store it in access again, there is no point, unless you are going to delete the source tables. If that is your process then a make table query as already suggested is by far the simplest route. Remeber that creating and deleting tables causes database files to "Bloat" and that you should compact and repair frequently to keep the DB size manageable.

Comment: @SeanLange Its a one time retrival, I get the data share it and keep it.
Export is the only worry.

Comment: @Minty The Make Table gives an error. Its not working.

Comment: You need to provide more information. "it gives an error" is not helpful. Providing the error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a "make table" based on the query within access.

See this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-make-table-query-787763ba-a9e4-42c0-b09f-98c01014808e

Comment: I get an Error "Size of field too long"

Comment: One or more of your output fields probably has more that 256 characters. You will need to identify which ones and change the field type to Memo for those fields.

Comment: If you have a field that had more than 255,  Excel will truncate.  You can fix that by repeating rows or adding fields to accommodate the SPLIT or just export to CSV.  Even that way you would need to crease a new output every 65k records.  Iterate!

Comment: My DESCRIPTION - column has more than 255 Char what can be done to that ?

Comment: Ok, if the "make table" query is giving too much "grief", here's another way to do the task:   1. create a table that has all the necessary fields [and data types] to store the query output data. 2. Create an "Insert query", instead of a make table to dump the info to the new table.   Know that the insert query will append the data if run twice (or more), so make sure to truncate the table between query runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this command:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "YourQuery", "C:\Test\export.csv", True
```

Comment: My DB is an ACCESS DB

Comment: Press `Ctrl+G`.

Comment: You need to provide more information. "it gives an error" is not helpful.